# Use ufw to block users from accessing my server via a specific vpn

Tags: ddos, ubuntu-18.04, ufw

The last couple of days I've been having some weird small DDoS attacks on different VPS's I have online.

The first one I detected using netstat and I noticed a bunch of IPs that were from a different region (resulting in Singapore) so I used `ufw deny from x.y.0.0/16` to block the entire subnet as it was varying on the last 2 numbers. That worked.

Now today I am having the same issue on a completely different VPS just that this time besides the IP there are also some addresses that say for example `miami-1.octovpn.net` (that's a real value in this case). I blocked the IP range in that case, but I am not sure how to block a wildcard domain from accessing the site using ufw.

I thought of something like:

```
ufw deny from *.octovpn.net
```

But the command returned `ERROR: Bad source address`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not been under attack from us, however if you look at the packets you received it was SYN_RECV. These packets can easily be spoofed.

**You** are being used as the **reflector** to attack us, not other way around.

There is no true way to stop this once you are being used as a reflector, due to how TCP works. What you can do is block our ranges - however, the attackers will still use you as a reflector to attack other services.

You can read more about it here: https://octovpn.com/tcpamp

We had to make this page as we saw a huge number of increase of attacks that were originating from "TCP-AMP" where remote TCP Services are being used as reflectors. Server administrators thought we are attacking them, but it's the opposite.

Comment: Oh, nice of you to join @OctoVPN and thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
nslookup miami-1.octovpn.net
```

giving

> Name:   miami-1.octovpn.net
>   Address: 45.77.95.134

With this address, do a

```
whois 45.77.95.134
```

which results in

> NetRange:       45.76.0.0 - 45.77.255.255
>   CIDR:           45.76.0.0/15

Now you can use the familiar

```
ufw deny from 45.76.0.0/15
```

---

The risk you run, is blocking more than necessary, because the owner of this IP range is not octovpn.net

---

*Update*: I missed the second part of the whois answer, which shows a subset of the IP range

> NetRange:       45.77.94.0 - 45.77.95.255
>   CIDR:           45.77.94.0/23

This allows to narrow the blocked range to

```
ufw deny from 45.77.94.0/23
```

Comment: Ok, that seem to have worked, but for some reason I still get connections to tcp6. What should be the way to block those?

Comment: Or perhaps I could disable ip6 temporarily?

Comment: I can't say, because `miami-1.octovpn.net` doesn't seem to have an IPv6 address. Maybe this is an unrelated case and/or another domain.

Comment: If disabling IPv6 doesn't harm accessibility to your servers, this may be an option.

Comment: It appears like `tcp6   0   0   myserver:https   miami-1.octovpn.n:16850 SYN_RECV`. At the moment only tcp6 connections appear active for those. I am going to turn IPv6 off to check if it fixes this.

Comment: What address is shown when you use numeric option, e.g. `ss -n` or `netstat -n`

Comment: I see just IPv4 addresses which is weird, because it's supposed to be tcp6 connection. What I tried was `ufw deny from 45.77.94.0/23 /tcp6` but it said invalid number of arguments.

Comment: In `ss -n` the peer addresses appear as `*`.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same deny instructions for tcp6?